# Debugging AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <tool> not found in arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, attributeerror, split-by-attribute

I have a problem executing the code below in ArcGIS 9.3.
The file is not found in split_row_0717.py

What should I modify?

The error said:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",
 
     line 310, in RunScript
     exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__   File "H:\python_p\python_code\split_row_0717.py", 
     line 46, in <module>
     gp.SplitByAttribute_Analysis2(fc, fieldName, outWorkspace, fieldName) AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment
 <SplitByAttribute_Analysis2> not found
```

---

The code that generates error:

```
##Script Name: split rows
##Description: using 
##Created By: Elaine Kuo
##Date: 12/07/2012


#Import standard library modules
import arcgisscripting
import os

#Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)


#Set the workspace.
gp.Workspace= "H:/temp/test"


#Set the workspace. List all of the feature classes in the dataset
outWorkspace= "H:/temp"

# Add a toolbox with a model to the geoprocessor and set the workspace
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program       Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolBox/Toolboxes/AdditionalAnalysis/Additional Analysis - Generic Tools.tbx")


#Get a list of the featureclasses in the input folder
fcs = gp.ListFeatureClasses()

# Loop through every item in the list that was just generated
for fc in fcs:

    # Break out the name, no path or extension, using the describe object.
    desc = gp.describe(fc)
    featureName = desc.name
  
    # Validate the new feature class name for the output workspace.
    OutFeatureClass = outWorkspace + os.sep + gp.ValidateTableName(fc,outWorkspace)

    #get file name
    fcName, fcExt = os.path.splitext(fc) 

    #build field name
    fieldName = fcName

    #### Execute Script Tool ####
    gp.SplitByAttribute_Analysis2(fc, fieldName, outWorkspace, fieldName)


gp.AddMessage(gp.GetMessages())
print gp.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be a problem with your filepath in this line:

```
# Add a toolbox with a model to the geoprocessor and set the workspace
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program       Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolBox/Toolboxes/AdditionalAnalysis/Additional Analysis - Generic Tools.tbx")
```

The spaces look off. I am assuming that `SplitByAttribute_Analysis2` is part of this toolbox though. Where possible, it makes things easier if you don't have spaces in your filenames (e.g. `Additional Analysis - Generic Tools` could be `AdditionalAnalysisGenericTools`